# Use touchstart or mousedown?

Tags: javascript

I write mousedown / mouseup event listener and it is able to work on my android phone , so is it not necessary for me to write touchstart functions for all the phones if I just need a simple touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your logic is working, why would you want to change it / add more event handlers?

I recommend reading [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) to determine for yourself whether or not you should use these specific handlers. Although it is iOS documentation, it gives you a good feel of how the mobile events are handled.

**More ontopic**:

If you just need a simple touch event, it seems to me that a 'click' event listener would be enough. If you want to do any scrolling / mouse(touch?) specific stuff, again: read [that documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

Comment: `click` is not a touch event, the biggest problem being the trigger delay of ~300ms.

Comment: @IngoBürk I know that click is not a touch event but mobile browsers do 'emulate' click events when the screen is touched. And FatDogMark just wants to handle 'a simple touch'.